# .ts is not imported into the react application, what should I do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

ERROR in ./src/store/store.ts 4:0-50
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../services/AuthService' in 'D:\DND\dnd1\src\store'

webpack compiled with 1 error and 4 warnings

I tried to import in different ways. But in any case, it does not work. The most important thing is that my react was originally a js project and I added it .ts files

```js
import {IUser} from '../models/IUser'
import {makeAutoObservable} from 'mobx'
import AuthService from '../services/AuthService';
// const AuthService = require ('../services/AuthService.ts')

export default class Store {
    user = {} as IUser;
    isAuth = false;
    
    constructor(){
        makeAutoObservable(this)
    } 

    setAuth(bool: boolean){
        this.isAuth = bool
    }

    setUser(user: IUser){
        this.user = user
    }

    async login(email: string, password: string){
        try {
            const response = await AuthService.login(email, password)
            localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.accessToken)
            this.setUser(response.data.user)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.response?.data?.message)
        }
    }

    async registration(email: string, password: string, name: string, lastname: string, surname: string){
        try {
            const response = await AuthService.registration(email, password, name, lastname, surname)
            localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.accessToken)
            this.setUser(response.data.user)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.response?.data?.message)
        }
    }

    async logout(){
        try {
            const response = await AuthService.logout()
            localStorage.removeItem('token')
            this.setAuth(false)
            this.setUser({} as IUser)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.response?.data?.message)
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to pinpoint the exact problem without knowing what your `webpack` configuration looks like, but my guess is that you don't have a loader for TypeScript files set up. I recommend adding something like the following to your `module.exports` and seeing if that solves your issue:

```js
module: {
  rules:[
    {
      test: /\.ts$/,
      use: 'ts-loader',
      include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')]
    }
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
},
```